# Calculate $\frac{2}{\sqrt5}\arctan\left( \tan\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt5} \right) $

Tags: trigonometry

How much is $$\frac{2}{\sqrt5}\arctan\left( \frac{\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt5} \right) $$ when $x = 2\pi$? I found it to be $0$, but the correct answer is supposed to be $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt5}$. How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 3):

> **Hint :** $$\arctan(\tan(x))=x ; ~\forall x \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

Answer given is wrong.It should be $\dfrac{2\pi}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

We can compute the following:

\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}\arctan\left( \frac{\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt5} \right)\\
f(2\pi)&=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}\arctan\left( \frac{\tan\frac{2\pi}{2}}{\sqrt5} \right)\tag{substitution}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}\arctan\left( \frac{\tan\pi}{\sqrt5} \right)\tag{cancel fraction}\\
&=\frac 2{\sqrt{5}}\arctan\left(\frac0{\sqrt{5}}\right)\tag{$\tan(\pi)=0$}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{5}}\times 0\tag{$\arctan(0)=0$}\\
&=0\end{align}

---

*The 'correct answer' is actually wrong, as confirmed by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Froot(5)%5Carctan((%5Ctan((2pi)%2F2))%5C(root(5))))*

Comment: My bad, I edited the post (I'm not very good with mathjax). It's all over sqrt5

Comment: @Lola [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Froot(5)%5Carctan((%5Ctan((2pi)%2F2))%5C(root(5))))) agrees with you that it is $0$